# Is there a difference between the pronunciation of 'use' as a verb and a noun?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

Is there a difference between how we pronounce:

> The verb "use"

and

> The noun 'use"

In other words, the transcription for the verb use is /ju:z/; is the transcription of the noun "use" also /ju:z/?

Comment: Any dictionary will tell you how the noun *use* is pronounced.

Comment: This may be regionally dependent, but for me, the verb is /juz/, and the noun is /jus/.

Comment: I could not find it, Would you please give me a link. I would appreciate that

Comment: @personallearner - If you do a Google search for "use pronunciation", you will find many results.

Comment: There are, by the way, other noun-verb pairs like this, sometimes reflected in the spelling: abuse/abuse, advice/advise; also refuse/refuse, but in that case the noun is stressed on the first syllable and the verb is stressed on the second. Lots of noun-verb pairs are like _that_: record/record, reject/reject, conduct/conduct, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Online Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/use) gives the pronunciation of the verb as /ju:z/, and that of the noun as /ju:s/.